# Best Practice for implementing ClickHandlers for Many Buttons

Tags: java, gwt, handler, rpc

I am currently designing a remote for a NAO robot with GWT and I'm looking for best practices to execute the supposed method of a button via a RPC. Currently I'm checking the buttons name with the title of event.getSource(). But this results in a huge amount of if else statements. How could I do it nice and neat? ;)

Comment: care to explain some more? the question is a bit vague. I guess what you want is a way to send the command to the server side code and from there to control the robot? What is your current implementation ( or Design ).

Comment: As I understand the button is clicked in a remote location and you want some code on the server end that is more elegant than a bunch of if then?

Comment: it currently looks like this:

`if (button.title == "walk")
//do stuff
else if (button.title == "sitdown")
//do other stuff
`
and so on... I guess there is a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an enum or an integer as identifier which you set with your Button constructor.Then on the server side you can save some lines of code with a switch case statement.

```
  public enum MyButtons {
  WALK,
  SIT,
   ...
   }
[...]
 //ON CLIENT
 Button whatever = new Button(MyButtons.WALK);

 //ON SERVER
 MyButtons action = whatever.getType(); 
// getType() should provide the value from the constructor


 switch(action)
   {
    case WALK : doStuff();
    case SIT : doStuff();
     ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use well named methods and some method reflection.

Lets say you have buttons named :
action1
action2
action3

if this was local you could add a different listener to each. since its remote and I understand you only get the name.

In your remote impl class have method called:

doAction1
doAction2
doAction3

And in the place where you get the remote call look at the name, make init letter upper case, add do then get the method. You can even cache the methods in a Map by name

Map

Once you have the method, call on it on the one instance worker

Comment: So you think a different listener for all buttons? There are about 15 buttons on the remote, that would be a lot of code, wouldnt it?
My question is, how is it implemented on other websites with many buttons?

Comment: i have code that has many listeners and suggest that as a solution for you for different actions. there is hardly any over head to have 15 or 100 more classes in the JVM or in your code repo. Will make the code clear and less messy